# List comparision in perl

Tags: regex, perl, hash

The command "sh value" gives

```
A: optimal
size: 100
feature : ON
Minimum size: 0
CPU load: 100%
```

Done

The name-value pairs written above are parameters wit default values.
I want to compare the values corresponding to each parameter with the output of the command sh value each time its fired and verify if they match correctly. If the values don't match I need to mark the parameter for which the match doesn't happen.

How to do it ? Also, is it possible to iterate over the list with match results displayed as iterations?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What did you try?

Comment: i was thinking of hash

Comment: Well, a hash sounds good. Hack up some code ideas, edit them into your questions wherever you get stuck and I'm sure there'll be help around. It's just that people don't want to do all your work for you...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to assume the order is constant (i.e. the following code will work whether it is or not). I am going to assume the order of the fields isn't significant.

1. For each line of the previous output,

   1. `split` the line on the first `:`.
   2. Create an element in `%prev_values`, where the key and value are the results of `split`.
2. For each line of the current output,

   1. `split` the line on the first `:`.
   2. Create an element in `%cur_values`, where the key and value are the results of `split`.
3. For each key in `%prev_values`,

   1. If the key doesn't exist in `%cur_values`,

      1. This key was deleted. Print an appropriate message.
4. For each key in `%cur_values`,

   1. If the key doesn't exists in `%prev_values`,

      1. This key is a new key. Print an appropriate message.
   2. Else

      1. If the value of that key in `%cur_values` different than the one in `%prev_values`,

         1. The value of this key changed. Print an appropriate message.